# Weird sound while watching videos

Tags: sound

Yesterday I installed Ubuntu 12.10. While playing videos I am getting weird audio for 5-10 seconds, but thereafter it works fine. However if I forward or backward the video again that weird sound starts.

I installed 12.04 some months back. There also I was getting that same sound but after some days that problem was gone. I don't know how to do it. Can you please guide me for this?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Your system might be busy in the background, even if the CPU is not 100%, the disk might be. Leave the system on for a while before watching video.

Comment: This not only happen with video. This happens with other applications which uses voice....